# React navigation array of routes from type definition

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

I've got a couple of routes, which are defined in ParamList type, as described in the docs. Now I've got a flow, which would require using them based on the index, so I converted them into an array, but since the keys are not strings with proper route names the navigation does not like that. Is there any way to apply the proper type to that array, which would be based on the keys from the ParamList?

```
export type ParamList = {
  Route1: undefined;
  Route2: undefined;
  Route3: undefined;
};
```

Comment: Your ParamList is an object, not an array!

Comment: I'm trying to say I've converted them into an array ['Route1', 'Route2', 'Route3'] and I'm trying to provide it with a type based on the ParamList type keys, which I'm using for the navigation